# What's the Ember.js controller naming convention?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, ember.js

I'm just getting started with Ember.js and trying to understand some conventions used amongst its projects and I wanna know if, for example, the proper nomenclature for controllers is `App.ApplicationController` or `App.applicationController`?

I've seen code examples of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ember naming conventions are pretty simple.
Words in uppercase are for class, and in lowercase for instances, as Peter Wagenet said:

> If it's a class or a namespace, it's uppercase; if it's an instance, it's lowercase.

I suggest you to read its post: [The Emberist: Naming convention](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html).

You can take a look at all the others posts in this blog, they are really interesting.

Comment: This is an important convention, as it is used by the injections that run on App.initialize to construct instances of your controllers and connect them to your router.